# Why does my existingClients count keep rising?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I've been tasked with some course work to repair some code. Each time the program runs, it gets progressively slower and slower. With the use of some breakpoints and profiling i think ive narrowed down the reason behind it however I'm unsure how to fix it.

this function is using alot of cpu and ive narrowed it down to my existingClient variable which is adding indefinitely
https://gyazo.com/67e44844a279a10e1b11165b941b1cf6

[image: the count keeps rising]

```
public void AddNewClientData()
{
  Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

  try {
    string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines("ClientList.csv");
    foreach(string line in fileLines)
    {
      string[] lineParts = line.Split(',');
      Client client = new Client()
      {
        ClientName = lineParts[0],
          ClientPhone = lineParts[1],
          EntryTime = DateTime.Parse(lineParts[2]),
          ExitTime = DateTime.Parse(lineParts[3])
      };

      bool clientExists = false;

      // Check that the user does not already exist
      string sqlGet = "Select * FROM ClientInOut";
      using(var connection = Helpers.GetConnection())
      {

        connection.Open();
        List < Client > existingClients = connection.Query<Client>(sqlGet).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < fileLines.Length; i++)
        {
          foreach(Client existingCustomer in existingClients)
          {

            if (existingCustomer == client) {
              clientExists = true;

            }
          }

        }

      }
    // add the new client 
    if (clientExists == false) {
      string sql =
        "INSERT INTO ClientInOut (ClientName, ClientPhone, EntryTime, ExitTime) Values (@ClientName, @ClientPhone, @EntryTime, @ExitTime);";
      using(var connection = Helpers.GetConnection())
      {
        connection.Open();
        var affectedRows = connection.Execute(sql, client);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I guess that `existingCustomer == client` returns `false` everytime. Maybe you should override the `Client.Equals` function, so it compares the fields and  not the objects themselves, and use it like `existingCustomer.Equals(client)` instead

Comment: I think I'd use a hash and store that along the client fields into to db. Then query with that hash instead of querying the complete list and iterating.

Comment: I see a very unnecessary neste foreach() loop, and finding the existing customer should be done in SQL anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`==` operator will compare objects references, therefore `existingCustomer == client` will return `false` (as they are different objects, so they do not share the same reference) and you'll always end up inserting your clients.

I'd recommend overriding `Equals` and use it instead of `==`.

See the following snippet (with only two properties to avoid noise):

```
using System.IO;
using System;

public class Client
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public string Phone { get;set; }
    
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if(other is Client)
        {
            var c2 = (Client)other;
            // Compare the properties instead of objects references
            return c2.Name == this.Name && c2.Phone == this.Phone;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Client c1 = new Client
        {
            Name = "Test",
            Phone = "0055512345"
        };
        Client c2 = new Client
        {
            Name = "Test",
            Phone = "0055512345"
        };
        
        Console.WriteLine(c1 == c2);      // returns false
        Console.WriteLine(c1.Equals(c2)); // returns true
    }
}
```

---

Note this is minimalist code, if you choose to go this way, you can improve it a lot:

- add `null` check in the `Equals` code
- use type pattern matching if you code with sufficiently recent c# version
- override `GetHashCode` as well to get rid of the warning
- etc

Comment: `== operator will compare whole objects`, thats not entirely true.
It will, per default, compare references of those objects (reference equality).